# Css modified after wordpress update

Tags: wordpress

I have updated my WordPress version. The style of the css is modified. I have a backup version. Should I take the oldest file for plugins and theme in order to resolve that issue?

Comment: I suggest you to create a backup  with Duplicator. Then try your luck.
Updating wordpress never change CSS of your theme.

Comment: too broad. just updating the WordPress should not change/remove any css of your website( may only be affected some layout of dashboard ). so, What did you update? and which files you want to copy-paste?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a child theme and put your custom css in the css-file from your child-theme.

Your child-theme would not touch from any update and your custom code is save

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress):

> WARNING: The upgrade process will affect all files and folders included in the main WordPress installation. This includes all the core files used to run WordPress. If you have made any modifications to those files, your changes will be lost.

When you do any theme changes you should always put your changes in either a custom theme you have made yourself (so only you update it), or if you're using someone else's theme, create a child theme.

More [information about child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) can be found here:

> A child theme is a theme that inherits the functionality and styling of another theme, called the parent theme. Child themes are the recommended way of modifying an existing theme.

As for plugins, they don't work in the same way so you'll need to make sure that any plugins you change are your own otherwise you'll lose the changes when you update them.

Lastly, you can also [use the WordPress Customiser](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#Custom_CSS_in_WordPress) (**Appearance > Customize in the dashboard**) if you don't want a child theme but want to insert custom CSS. That allows you to edit CSS safely within the dashboard and keep your changes safe even when you update things.